# Error when using PyPlot in Julia

Tags: matplotlib, julia

I've studied Julia for several months and I am not an expert in programming. Recently, I re-installed Windows on my laptop and re-installed Julia, Anaconda(for python 3) and Atom, so far.

In Julia, I installed PyPlot.jl by `Pkg.add("PyPlot")` and want to test plotting with PyPlot. So, I put `using PyPlot` in Julia and it give an error during initialization of module PyPlot. I've got the following error message:

> ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(330): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.6.2-vc9_3'.
>   UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', '        1\xb0\xb3 \xc6\xc4\xc0\xcf\xc0\xcc \xba\xb9\xbb\xe7\xb5\xc7\xbe\xfa\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9.\r\n', 9, 10, 'invalid start byte')
>
> Attempting to roll back.
>
> UnicodeDecodeError('utf8', '        1\xb0\xb3 \xc6\xc4\xc0\xcf\xc0\xcc \xba\xb9\xbb\xe7\xb5\xc7\xbe\xfa\xbd\xc0\xb4\xcf\xb4\xd9.\r\n', 9, 10, 'invalid start byte')

Please let me know how I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by using python in Anaconda.

> ENV["PYTHON"]="C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python"

In the double quotation marks, put the location of the python which is installed by Anaconda.

After that, apply

> Pkg.build("PyCall")
>
> Pkg.build("PyPlot")

I now can use PyPlot `using PyPlot` as before. It seems there was some problem to use python included in Julia.

Comment: But, still have some problem to install IJulia. Similar error message come out when I type `Pkg.add("IJulia")` or `Pkg.bulid("IJulia")`.